# How do I see the name of a logged in user?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm trying to access the current logged in user's name, and get it working in the Playground right now for apollo graphql. I'm using Prisma and I'm a beginner.

This is my schema.graphql:

```
type Query {
  info: String!
  userlist: [User!]!
  me: User
}

type Mutation {
  signup(email: String!, password: String!, name: String!): AuthPayload
  login(email: String!, password: String!): AuthPayload
}

type AuthPayload {
  token: String
  user: User
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  email: String!
}
```

Here is my src/resolvers/Query.js:

```
const { getUserId } = require("../utils");

function userlist(parent, args, context) {
  return context.prisma.user.findMany();
}

function me(parent, args, context) {
  const id = getUserId(context);
  return context.prisma.user({ id });
}

module.exports = {
  userlist,
  me,
};
```

How do I test this in the playground? If I log in a user with this query:

```
mutation {
  login(email: "alice@prisma.io", password: "graphql") {
    token
    user {
      email
      
    }
  }
}
```

Then when I try to display "me" I get this:

```
query {
  me {
      id
      name
    }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'authorization')",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "me"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'authorization')",
            "    at getUserId (/Users/username/example-3/server/src/utils.js:10:36)",
            "    at me (/Users/username/example-3/server/src/resolvers/Query.js:8:14)",
           // i deleted a bunch of stuff here, let me know if you would like to see it and I'll add it back
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "me": null
  }
}
```

This is the utils.js:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const APP_SECRET = "GraphQL-is-aw3some";

function getTokenPayload(token) {
  return jwt.verify(token, APP_SECRET);
}

function getUserId(req, authToken) {
  if (req) {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    if (authHeader) {
      const token = authHeader.replace("Bearer ", "");
      if (!token) {
        throw new Error("No token found");
      }
      const { userId } = getTokenPayload(token);
      return userId;
    }
  } else if (authToken) {
    const { userId } = getTokenPayload(authToken);
    return userId;
  }

  throw new Error("Not authenticated");
}

module.exports = {
  APP_SECRET,
  getUserId,
};
```

Do I need to pass in the auth token somehow? Any idea why getUserId isn't working? I think I have something wrong, because the code I was using from an example has getUserId(req), but another solution I saw has getUserId(context), so is that what is wrong here? How do I change my Query to use req instead of context? I'm not understanding them enough to make this change.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question:

> Do I need to pass in the auth token somehow?

Yes. You're getting an error because you're not passing *any* headers from the [playground](https://blog.logrocket.com/complete-guide-to-graphql-playground/) so `req.headers` is undefined.

At the bottom left of the playground there's an area where you can define query variables and headers. Define one called "authorization" and put a valid token in the contents.

You should have a login method somewhere that creates a valid token, use that.